# Matplotlib errorbar fails to read a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have two data frames in pandas format that I am trying to plot as values and error bars. But the python interface complains about some error  I cannot understand. I have tested a colleague's almost the same code, and it appears that the fact that I run python 3.5 while he utilizes 2.7, is the source of the error. Therefore, I did test his code on my computer (python 3.5) and I am getting the same error message.

Bellow is a subset of my troubling code:

```
"Using pandas library to combine the three white spruce data sets"
trees = [white_spruce_1,white_spruce_2,white_spruce_3]
ntrees = pd.concat(trees) # Concatenate list into a series
spruce_stat = ntrees.groupby("Wvl") #Converted the series into a panda object

mean_spruce = spruce_stat.mean()
std_spruce = spruce_stat.std()
#mean_spruce.head()
mean_spruce['wvl']=mean_spruce.index
mean_spruce.head()

     Chan.# Rad. (Ref.) Rad. (Target)   Tgt./Ref. %
Wvl             
350     0        0       0.000014        0.686176
351     0        0       0.000015        0.707577

std_spruce.head()

       Chan.#   Rad. (Ref.) Rad. (Target)   Tgt./Ref. %
Wvl             
350       0       0          0.000014        0.686176
351       0       0          0.000015        0.707577

plt.errorbar(mean_spruce['wvl'],mean_spruce['Tgt./Ref. %'], xerr = None, yerr = std_spruce['Rad. (Ref.)'])
```

Bellow is the error message I receive:

```
KeyError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-13352d94b09c> in <module>()
      2 #plt.errorbar(mean_spruce['wvl'],mean_spruce['Tgt./Ref. %'], xerr = None,yerr=std_spruce['Tgt./Ref. %'],c='k',ecolor='r', elinewidth=0.5, errorevery=5)
      3 #plt.errorbar( x, y, xerr = None , yerr = sd_white_spruce['Tgt./Ref. %'],c = 'green', ecolor = 'red', capsize = 0,elinewidth = 0.5, errorevery = 5 )
----> 4 plt.errorbar(mean_spruce['wvl'],mean_spruce['Tgt./Ref. %'], xerr = None, yerr = std_spruce['Rad. (Ref.)'])# ,c = 'green', ecolor = 'red', capsize = 0,elinewidth = 0.5, errorevery = 5)
      5 

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in errorbar(x, y, yerr, xerr, fmt, ecolor, elinewidth, capsize, barsabove, lolims, uplims, xlolims, xuplims, errorevery, capthick, hold, data, **kwargs)
   2828                           xlolims=xlolims, xuplims=xuplims,
   2829                           errorevery=errorevery, capthick=capthick, data=data,
-> 2830                           **kwargs)
   2831     finally:
   2832         ax.hold(washold)

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1809                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1810                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1811             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1812         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1813         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in errorbar(self, x, y, yerr, xerr, fmt, ecolor, elinewidth, capsize, barsabove, lolims, uplims, xlolims, xuplims, errorevery, capthick, **kwargs)
   2961                 # Check for scalar or symmetric, as in xerr.
   2962                 if len(yerr) > 1 and not ((len(yerr) == len(y) and not (
-> 2963                         iterable(yerr[0]) and len(yerr[0]) > 1))):
   2964                     raise ValueError("yerr must be a scalar, the same "
   2965                                      "dimensions as y, or 2xN.")

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    555     def __getitem__(self, key):
    556         try:
--> 557             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    558 
    559             if not np.isscalar(result):

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3882 
   3883         k = _values_from_object(key)
-> 3884         loc = self.get_loc(k)
   3885         new_values = _values_from_object(series)[loc]
   3886 

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3940             pass
   3941         return super(Float64Index, self).get_loc(key, method=method,
-> 3942                                                  tolerance=tolerance)
   3943 
   3944     @property

C:\Users\mike\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1757                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   1758             key = _values_from_object(key)
-> 1759             return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1760 
   1761         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method,

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:9556)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:9494)()

KeyError: 0.0
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, explaining the error is pretty easy - at some point the value `0.0` is being used as a key (I'm assuming for a df), and that's not allowed, as it's a float, not an int. You can't index for row 1.7, for example.

Comment: I am still in the dark, where in my code is a 0.0 key called? The column std_spruce[Tgt./Ref. % ] was plotted and there are no values even close to 0.  The code runs well at my friends computer. I appreciate any help

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem, but consider using `mean_spruce = mean_spruce.reset_index()` instead of `mean_spruce['wvl']=mean_spruce.index` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: @Arcticpython if the code runs on another computer, then there may be an issue with pandas itself. What version are you running (`pd.__version__`) on each machine? I'd recommend updating to 0.17.1 if you can.

Comment: I am running 0.17.1. It appears that my code, and my friends code does not work on his computer any more. So our current hypothesis, is that the code worked on his computer on an earlier Pandas/Anaconda version and the new version has some bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the discrepancy between the Pandas indexing and the indexing of Matplotlib internal functions. One way to resolve it -albeit not being elegant- is to create a dummy dataframe just for the plotting purpose. In your case:

```
mean_spruce_dummy = mean_spruce
mean_spruce_dummy.columns = np.arange(0, len(mean_spruce))
```

In principle, this discrepancy is solved in the newer version of Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar error in python 2.7. My solution is to access the underlying data directly. This should work for you

```
x = mean_spruce['wvl'].values
y = mean_spruce['Tgt./Ref. %'].values
yerr = std_spruce['Rad. (Ref.)'].values

plt.errorbar(x, y yerr=yerr)
```